# Error : error: package SpotsDialog does not exist

Tags: android, firebase

I am following an Android tutorial to create a google account firebase authentication In onCreate function. I am not getting any suggestion for SpotsDialog package so it is giving an Error but it works fine in above video?

https://youtu.be/4h4y4mnJIBs?t=852

can't resolve symbol 'SpotsDialog'
this is in my onCreate() function

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    configureGoogleSignIn();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    signInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();

        }
    });

    waiting_dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this)
            .setMessage("please wait ..")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .build();
}
```

and I have created AlertDialoge above.

```
AlertDialog waiting_dialog;
```

Comment: please explain it more. nobody will goto Youtube to watch video and help

Comment: Probably, you missed dependency for dialog

Comment: Which dependency I need to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, You need to include `SpotsDialog` library. add below line under dependencies section in build.gradle(Module: app) file

```
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
```

For more info check [SpotsDialog Library](https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add the spots dialog library.

site:- https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog

add this on build.gradle(Module: app) file

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Please follow the below steps:

**Step1:** Add `SpotDialog` dependency to your `build.gradle(app):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
}
```

**Step2:** Make a global `AlertDialog` object inside your class and above your `onCreate()`:

```
AlertDialog waiting_dialog;
```

**Step3:** Then in your `onCreate()` after `setContentView(..)` initialize the object:

```
waiting_dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder()
                    .setContext(this)
                    .setMessage(R.string.app_name)
                    .setCancellable(false)
                    .build()
```

**Finally**, Show and Dismiss the dialog wherever you want to:

```
waiting_dialog.show();
```

&

```
waiting_dialog.dismiss();
```

Hope it helps.